# How to do not select case of two items if you have only one item in list

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

Maybe it is silly question, but I am quite new in C#. I have such a object:

```
MyStructure data = new MyStructure()
{
    Name = "Test",
    DateTime = "2017-07-14T00:00:00.000Z",
    Items = new List<ItemsRequest>
    {
        new ItemsRequest() { Type = ItemsType.Green, Id = "0020012321" }
    }
};
```

And I have method where I am validating such structure:

```
var badRequests = new Dictionary<Func<bool>, string>
{

    [() => myStructure.Name == null] = "Name parameter cannot be empty or null string",
    [() => (myStructure.ItemsRequest[0].Type == ItemsType.Green &&
        myStructure.ItemsRequest[0].Id == myStructure.ItemsRequest[0].Id && yStructure.ItemsRequest[1].Type == ItemsType.Red &&
        myStructure.ItemsRequest[1].Id == myStructure.ItemsRequest[1].Id)] = "could not be created with one with these types",
};
```

This validation DO NOT pass, because there aren't 2 items in my object, but I am getting such a error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

How can I handle it when I have only one item in list and do not get error? As I understand it is because of indexes [] .

Edit: When I have such a structure with one item:

```
MyStructure data = new MyStructure()
{
    Name = "Test",
    DateTime = "2017-07-14T00:00:00.000Z",
    Items = new List<ItemsRequest>
    {
        new ItemsRequest() { Type = ItemsType.Green, Id = "0020012321" }
    }
};
```

And in dictionary I validate only this function, it pass succesfully, because I select only one item with specific entries.

```
[() => myStructure.ItemsRequest.Select(x => x.Type == ItemsType.Green && x.Id == "0020012321").FirstOrDefault()] = "Type cannot be Green",
```

But is there are any possibilities to be independent of indexes and select as many as you like items from object?

Comment: Before the clause checking `myStruture.ItemsRequest[1]` add a clause `&& myStructure.ItemsRequest.Count > 1` It will short-circuit the rest of the checks and return false. This is assuming you want having only one item to fail. If having only one item is supposed to pass, then you'd use an OR `||` instead.

Comment: You can use `.ForEach` to iterate through the `Items` list instead of trying to hard-code indexes.

Comment: @MattBurland I tried, but doesn't work.

Comment: @BinaryTie: Then you put it in the wrong place, or you are doing something else. Look at Rene's answer. You need to check the count _before_ any clause that attempts to access `[1]`.

Comment: @BinaryTie i think you've got somthing wrong in your code. You define `data` as `MyStructure` but after you access `myStructure`. Also.shouldn't be `Items[]` instead of `ItemsRequest[]`?

Comment: Why are you using `Func<bool>` as a key, and how exactly are you invoking the `Func` with your type of `MyStructure`?

Comment: @ColinM here is a answer : [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153466/119938)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code has been tested and works fine, if this doesn't work (as you previously mentioned on a comment) then there must be something else wrong with your code.

I have changed the `Dictionary<Func<bool>, string>` to `Dictionary<Predicate<MyStructure>, string>`, `Predicate<T>` will return true or false based on your condition - and it will take a parameter of `T`, which in this case will be a parameter of type `MyStructure` - this allows you to define your collection outside of the method.

```
class Program
{
    // Create a Dictionary of Key type Predicate<MyStructure>, Predicate returns true or false - no need for a Func<bool>
    private static Dictionary<Predicate<MyStructure>, string> badRequests = new Dictionary<Predicate<MyStructure>, string>
    {
        [p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Name)] = "Name parameter cannot be empty or null string",
        [p => p.Items.Count == 2 /* <- This is important, as René pointed out in his answer */ && p.Items[0].Type == ItemsType.Green &&
               p.Items[0].Id == "0020012321" && p.Items[1].Type == ItemsType.Red &&
               p.Items[1].Id == "9023546547"
        ] = "could not be created with one with these types"
    };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize object
        MyStructure data = new MyStructure()
        {
            Name = "Test",
            DateTime = "2017-07-14T00:00:00.000Z",
            Items = new List<ItemsRequest>
                {
                    new ItemsRequest() { Type = ItemsType.Green, Id = "0020012321" },
                    new ItemsRequest() { Type = ItemsType.Red, Id = "9023546547" }
                }
        };

        // Call badRequests Dictionary with data to fetch Value
        string myString = badRequests.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key.Invoke(data)).Value;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class MyStructure
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DateTime { get; set; }
        public List<ItemsRequest> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemsRequest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public ItemsType Type { get; set; }
    }


    public enum ItemsType
    {
        Green, Red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add test the `Count` of the list before accessing:

```
() => (myStructure.ItemsRequest.Count == 2 && // <-- add this line
       myStructure.ItemsRequest[0].Type == ItemsType.Green &&           
       myStructure.ItemsRequest[0].Id == "0020012321" &&
       myStructure.ItemsRequest[1].Type == ItemsType.Red &&
       myStructure.ItemsRequest[1].Id == "9023546547")
```

The expression is evaluated "short-circuited", so if `Count` is not `2`, the rest of the expression is not evaluated and so you don't try to access index `1` of the list if there is no second element.

Comment: I am getting same message.

Comment: @BinaryTie Then there must be some other mistake not shown in the code you posted. Can you post some more code? Where/when do you _execute_ the checks, where is this exception raised?

Comment: there isn't any mistakes, because this dictionary pass when I am validating with two items, also if I will change that code to `[() => myStructure.ItemsRequest.Select(x => x.Type == ItemsType.Green && x.Id == "0020012321").FirstOrDefault()] = "Type cannot be Green",`  it will validate, because it validates only one item, but I need to have in validations structure that in will work in any scenarios, when I have 3 or 5 items, but I need validation for example only when there are 2 items.

Comment: @BinaryTie well obviously there is a mistake. I tested the code as far as I can imagine what you do with that dictionary and it's `Func<bool>` keys. As long as you don't provide a reproducable example I'm afraid I can't help no more than that.

Comment: @BinaryTie if there was no mistake, there would be no question.